# Change to most recently used tab when closing a tab in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs

When I close an editor tab in IntelliJ, the tab that appears directly to the right of it gets opened next. Instead, I would rather have the most recently used tab open instead.

For example, if I have these tabs open:

```
Foo.java (currently viewed)
Bar.java
```

And then I use CMD+SHIFT+N to open `Baz.java`, it now looks like this:

```
Foo.java
Baz.java (currently viewed)
Bar.java
```

If I then close `Baz.java`, rather than returning to `Foo.java`, it goes to `Bar.java`.

```
Foo.java
Bar.java (currently viewed)
```

How can I configure the editor to go back to the most recently used tab?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to Settings/Editor/General/Editor Tabs

And select *Activate most recently opened tab* for the *When closing active editor* option.

[image]

Comment: `Most recently used` is not the same as `most recently opened`, though.

Comment: @Bloke In this case it is. When you use the _Activate most recently opened tab_ option, it activates the tab that was last focused/displayed rather than the tab that was last opened (e.g. from project view)... so, yes, the configuration option naming might be a little innacurate but it behaves exactly the way OP wanted it to behave.

Comment: I'm using the last version of intelij and it is still not the default option...

Comment: This trips me up every time - choosing "the editor to the left" seems like such a weird default.