# WebStorm - How to focus on the most recent opened tab when closing file

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm not sure if this is a bug or this is normal behaviour.

I'm using WebStorm on Mac (I think I remember having the same behaviour on Windows but I'm not sure).

I have always many files open. When I close a file, WebStorm is not doing what I want:

- Expected behaviour:

The focus is on the most recently used tab, i.e. on the last file I had focus on before focusing on the file that I closed.

- Actual behaviour:

The focus goes on the file where its name is the closest alphabetically. I'm not entirely sure that is the behaviour but it is definitely not on the Most recent used file.

Example with file names:

I have 5 tabs open, the most recent used tab list look like
[image]

So when I will close `navbar.controller.js`, I expect `changeLanguage.controller.js` to have the focus.

But instead when I closed it, the focus went on `jwt.js`
[image]

This is super confusing as in real work environment, I am used to have ~20tabs open and this confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a lot, it seems that the answer was already provided on this wonderful website: [Change to most recently used tab when closing a tab in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354825/change-to-most-recently-used-tab-when-closing-a-tab-in-intellij-idea)